# my app is getting crash while running on device

Tags: objective-c, ios4

my app is working fine on simulator but when i am running on device its getting crash and showing these reports

- Aug 11 15:02:04 unknown MobileMail[20218] : Received memory warning.
- Aug 11 15:02:04 unknown UserEventAgent[12] : jetsam: kernel termination snapshot   being created
- Aug 11 15:02:04 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xc8a9]) Exited: Killed: 9
- Aug 11 15:02:04 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x828b]) Exited: Killed: 9
- Aug 11 15:02:04 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.christopher.pacificamodeling[0x8500]) Exited: Killed: 9
- Aug 11 15:02:04 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.skype.skype[0xd976]) Exited: Killed: 9
- Aug 11 15:02:05 unknown SpringBoard[16688] : Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
- Aug 11 15:02:05 unknown SpringBoard[16688] : Application 'PacifiCA' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
- Aug 11 15:02:06 unknown SpringBoard[16688] : Application 'Skype' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
- Aug 11 15:02:06 unknown SpringBoard[16688] : Application 'Phone' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
- Aug 11 15:02:06 unknown DTPower[15342] : Task info failed for task com.christopher.pacificamodeling
- Aug 11 15:02:06 unknown kernel[0] : launchd[20223] Builtin profile: MobileMail (sandbox)
- Aug 11 15:02:06 unknown kernel[0] : launchd[20224] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
- Aug 11 15:02:06 unknown kernel[0] : launchd[20224] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/6BBDF6EB-1DB0-4CAB-8300-DC6CBA78C1AB [69] (sandbox)

Comment: Can you run it in simulator with profiler to check the memory usage it seems you are using a lot of memory which is fine on the PC but not good for the device.

Comment: ya.can u tell me how to avoid these memory warnings

Comment: Can you share the code that is causing the memory warning(s) and tell me the profile output it should mark the lines that allocate huge amount of memory blocks.

Comment: i tired to run it,but is showing target failed to run

Comment: and my code 

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning  
{  
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];  
     SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];  
    [imageCache clearDisk];  
    [imageCache cleanDisk];  
    [imageCache clearMemory];  
}

Comment: You will get memory warnings when there is little memory left. You can avoid this by having a correct memory management. Do you use ARC ? If you don't, try to profile using the Leaks Instrument and find out where you are leaking memory. Also , profile using Allocations and see what fills up your memory. Try to avoid keeping images in memory for example. That's bad. Keep a string that represents the images's path and write the image on the disk at that path.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if you managed to open the Profiler or not.

Comment: ya.i opened it and working on it only is it possible to check thats leaks while running on device?..@MahmoudFayez

Comment: @George.i already converted to ARC but still getting the problem

Comment: ARC won't magically fix memory abuse.   Short and simple, you are using too much memory.  Reduce memory use to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to run the profiler from xcode menu as shown below:

[image: Profiler]

then use the one highlighted below:

[image]

Finally you will see the blocks that is allocated the most expand any of them to see who is allocating it frequently. Go to that part and optimize it to avoid allocate/deallocate every time.

[image]